# Calculate success rate of Prometheus metrics and display in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have the following metrics:

files_processed_counter_total which is a counter that is incremented when a file is processed. It can fail or succeed so label is Failure or success.

I want to calculate the success rate so I am using this PromQL query:

```
(sum({__name__=~"files_processed_counter_total", _namespace_="myproject"}) - sum({__name__=~"files_processed_counter_total", _namespace_="myproject", filingStatus="failure"}))/sum({__name__=~"files_processed_counter_total", _namespace_=~"myproject"})*100
```

Could anyone help me if this looks correct? Currently, this is not displaying anything even though I get 100% success. So files_processed_counter_total = 1 with filingStatus= success. It should display something.

Comment: Looks correct. Can you check if second selector (the one with `filingStatus="failure"`) returns anything?